# How to click on a Dropdown menu through Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriver, mousehover

```
Actions a= new Actions(driver);
WebElement mainmenu=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui-gen2']/a"));
a.moveToElement(mainmenu).build().perform();
WebElement Sub = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='helpAbout']"));    
a.moveToElement(Sub).build().perform();
Sub.click();
```

Code  couldn't able to click on submenu it just stops at 3rd line.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Add the error that you're getting, if any and the HTML for better debugging. Without this there is not way to know what is going incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

With selenium you should be able to just do the following:

```
Select variableName = new Select(DropDownElementLocator);
variableName.selectByVisibleText("Whatever");
// or
variableName.selectByIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is 90% correct, just replace following code:

```
a.moveToElement(Sub).click().perform();
```

`build()` method works for hover on element,and after hover on it we have to click element.

Answer (score 0):

Once you *Mouse Hover* over the element identified as `By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui-gen2']/a")` and therefafter invoke `moveToElement(mainmenu)`, `build()`, `perform()`, at this stage the element identified as `By.xpath(".//*[@id='helpAbout']")` is *visible* and *interactable*. So you need to invoke `click()` directly as follows :

```
Actions a= new Actions(driver);
WebElement mainmenu=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui-gen2']/a"));
a.moveToElement(mainmenu).build().perform();
WebElement Sub = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='helpAbout']"));    
Sub.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

WebElement selectElement; 
selectElement= driver.findElement(By.id("yourElementId"));
  or 
selectElement driver.findElement(By.xpath("yourElementXpath"));

Select selectObject = new Select(selectElement);
```

The Select object will now give you a series of commands that allow you to interact with a  element. First of all, there are different ways of selecting an option from the  element.

```
<select>
<option value=value1>Bread</option>
<option value=value2 selected>Milk</option>
<option value=value3>Cheese</option>
</select>

// Select an <option> based upon the <select> element's internal index
selectObject.selectByIndex(1);

// Select an <option> based upon its value attribute
selectObject.selectByValue("value1");

// Select an <option> based upon its text. Example: Bread
selectObject.selectByVisibleText("Bread");
```